# How do you test exception in spring rest controller?

Tags: java, spring, rest, mockito, mockmvc

I am trying to test if exception was thrown in my rest controller. Here is my rest controller:

```
@DeleteMapping
public ResponseEntity<Void> cancel(@RequestParam long id) {
    if(id < 1) {
       throw new MyException();
    }
    try {
       doSomething();
    }
   catch (SomeException e) {
      throw new MyException();
   }
}
```

And here is my test:

```
private MockMvc mockMvc;

@BeforeMethod
public void beforeMethod() {
    initMocks(this);
    mockMvc = standaloneSetup(new StudyDispatcherController(studyDispatcherService)).build();
}

@Test (expectedExceptions = MyException.class)
public void cancelWithInvalidParam() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(delete(BASE_URL).param("id", "-1").contentType("application/json").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).andExpect(status().isBadRequest());

@Test (expectedExceptions = MyException.class)
public void cancelWithException() throws Exception {
    doThrow(SomeException.class).when(myService).doSomething();
    mockMvc.perform(delete(BASE_URL).param("id", "123").contentType("application/json").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).andExpect(status().is5xxServerError());
}
```

However, it throws 
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed;

How do I handle this in correct ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try the below code instead of cancelWithInvalidParam() method

```
@Test (expectedExceptions = Exception.class)
public void cancelWithInvalidParam() throws Exception {
mockMvc.perform(delete(BASE_URL).param("id", "-1").contentType("application/json").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).andExpect(status().isBadRequest());
```

Comment: All the exceptions are get handled in Exception.class

Comment: @JonathanHagen : You can accept answer if it is worked for you.